# Trouble in sending arduino sensor data to mysql databse via python script

Tags: python, mysql, database, arduino, sensors

I am using DHT11 humidity sensor, Dallas18B20 temperature sensor,reed switch and  hole effect sensor with arduino. I inserted two sensor data(humidity and temperature) into database successfully.But when I try to insert four sensor data to database it is not inserting any of data to the database.Following is my code.I honestly know what is done by pieces[0],pieces[1] here. I referred a example code and did this.for temperature and humidity sensors I wrote `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO weatherdata(DateTime,HUMIDITY,TEMPERATUREc) VALUES (NOW(),%s,%s)",(pieces[0],pieces[1]))` and it worked perfectly fine. I checked reed switch and hole effect sensors.They are working fine.Please help me on this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
import time
import MySQLdb
#establish connection to MYSQL.
dbConn=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","raspberry","weather") or die ("could not connect to database")
#open a cursor to the database
device="""/dev/ttyACM0"""
try:
    print "Trying...",device
    arduino=serial.Serial(device,9600)
except:
    print"Failed to connect on",device
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        data=arduino.readline() #read data from arduino
        print data
        pieces=data.split("\t") #split data by tab
        try:
            cursor=dbConn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO weatherdata(DateTime,WINDmph,HUMIDITY,RAINmm,TEMPERATUREc) VALUES (NOW(),%s,%s,%s,%s)",(pieces[0],pieces[1],pieces[2],pieces[3]))
            dbConn.commit()
 #commit the insert
            cursor.close() #close the cursor
        except MYSQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print"failed to insert data"
        finally:
            cursor.close() # close incase it failed
    except:
        print"Processing!"
```

Comment: This is likely a problem with python, MySQL, _or_ the arduino, not all three. Are you getting an error message? Is an empty row being written to your table? If you put in some print statements can you see if there are values in pieces[0], pieces[1], etc...?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.No any empty row is being sent.It is not showing all four data when i give print command.most of the times it prints only temperature and humidity values,rarely it gives temperature,humidity and wind values and sometimes humidity,rain and temperature values.Not all four

Comment: Sounds like it's an arduino issue then, which I don't know much about. If you're using multiple sensors they might not all be producing readings at the same time, so you'd have to preserve the values until you had a value for all four to insert into the table. Sorry I can't be more helpful, good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much,It is a good hint.I will try to change time intervals for four sensors in arduino code